# destructuring multiple times for the same object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Sometimes I do nested destructing, meaning more than a level, it can be dangerous but I only ensure the property exist otherwise I'll have the property of *undefined error*.

I did this recently,

```
const {
        match: {
          params: { id: UserId }
        },
        match
      } = this.props
```

and I have doubt whether is good code. I need `match.params.id`, and I also need the `match` object, so this duplicated 'variable' is fine?

Answer (score 1):

no do it like this:

```
const {match} = this.props;
const {params: {id: userId} = {} } = match || {};
```

Comment: Great. Isn't this is enough? `const {params: {id: userId} } = match;`?

Comment: Not only more readable but consider the case if the match or params were undefined destruction like you did will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Tarek said, that is the better way to do it. Just to check that the object and its properties are indeed valid.

This is also a good opportunity to check out the optional chaining operator! It is an experimental babel plugin that will (hopefully) be added to ES9!

Check it out [here!](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)

This is doing exactly what you would want in a much cleaner and simpler way.